# Error with VAO on Nexus 4 device only

Tags: opengl-es, nexus-4, vao

I've got a strange error on my nexus 4 with OpenGL ES2 when I use vertex array objects.

Here is some informations:

- Everything work when I don't use VAO
- Everything work on others device and on an Ipad 2 with and without VAO
- glGetError() didn't return error
- Due to the error some glitch appear in the game (some elements take another apparence)
- My VBO are dynamics (I update them with glBufferData)

Here is the error:

> Adreno-ES20(16818): : validate_vertex_attrib_state: No vertex attrib is enabled in a draw call!

And here is my code:

```
void Renderer::setVertexBuffer( Uint32 stream, const Base* vertexBuffer, std::size_t stride, Uint32 startVertex, Uint32 endVertex )
{
    static const bool VAOSupported = this->isExtensionPresent(VertexArrayObject);
    if( VAOSupported )
    {
        if( vertexBuffer->vao.isReady() == false )
        {
            // Bind VAO.
            glBindVertexArrayOES( vertexBuffer->vao.getId() );

            // Bind filled VBO.
            glCheck( glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer->getId() ) );

            // Set attributs with vertex format.
            this->applyVertexFormat( startVertex, endVertex );

            // Unbind buffer and VAO.
            glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

            vertexBuffer->vao.isReady(true);
        }

        glBindVertexArrayOES( vertexBuffer->vao.getId() );
    }
    else
    {
        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
        glCheck( glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer->getId() ) );
        this->applyVertexFormat( startVertex, endVertex );
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Renderer::setIndexBuffer( const Buffer* indexBuffer, std::size_t stride )
{
    glCheck( glBindBuffer( GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer->getId() ) );
    this->usedIndexBufferStride = stride;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Renderer::applyVertexFormat( Uint32 startVertex, Uint32 endVertex )
{
    const Uint32 stride = this->vertexFormat->getStride();
    for( Uint32 i = 0; i < this->vertexFormat->getAttributCount(); i++ )
    {
        const VertexElement& element = this->vertexFormat->getAttribut(i);

        glCheck( glEnableVertexAttribArray( element.usage ) );
        glCheck( glVertexAttribPointer( element.usage,
                                       element.type,
                                       element.type,
                                       element.normalize,
                                       stride,
                                       BUFFER_OFFSET(element.offset + startVertex * stride ) ) );
    }
}
```

And here is how I use it :

```
renderer->setFormat(geometry->getFormat()); // Only save a pointer to the format to use in apply method.
renderer->setVertexBuffer(geometry->getVertexBuffer());
renderer->setIndexBuffer(geometry->getIndexBuffer());
renderer->draw(GL_TRIANGLES, geometry->indiceCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `usage` is an appropriate name for the field that defines which attribute array to associate the pointer with? Buffer objects already have a property called usage (e.g. `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`). `location` might make more sense.

#### You have a much more serious issue in your code, however:

`element.type` cannot be *both* the type of your data and the number of components. `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` only accepts **1**, **2**, **3** or **4** components, an enumerant like `GL_FLOAT` has a value ***much*** larger than **4**.

Assuming `glCheck( ... )` correctly wraps `glGetError (...)`, this situation should be indicating **`GL_INVALID_VALUE`**.

This leads me to believe that your loop in `void Renderer::applyVertexFormat( Uint32 startVertex, Uint32 endVertex )` is never triggered.

Comment: Oups, that is an error during my copy/paste from my code, this error isn't present (with glVertexAttribPointer).

"This leads me to believe that your loop" -> I've added a printf to test and program go in this part of the code, very strange problem. I will try to debug OpenGL with eclipse tools to see commands order and see if the command are correctly call. Thanks!